# Can a ghost possess a vampire or any other undead?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, undead, possession

In my campaign, I'm planning to have an NPC ghost possess an NPC vampire.

Is this even possible?

Comment: "The vampire twitches spasmodically, and then attempts to shakes his[her] body of the apparition. "  I think it depends on the relative level of the ghost to the vamp whether it succeeds.

Answer (score 39):

The answer to your question is of course yes, because as the DM, you control the world, and things work how you say they work.  If that's how ghosts and vampires work in your world, then that's how it works.

What I imagine you actually meant is whether the official ghost in the Monster Manual can possess an official vampire in the Monster Manual, to which the answer is no.  The Possession ability specifies that it targets a humanoid:

> One humanoid that the ghost can see within 5 ft. of it must succeed on a DC 13 Charisma saving throw or be possessed by the ghost...

and a Vampire is not technically a humanoid but an undead:

> Vampire
>
> Medium undead (shapechanger), lawful evil

Humanoid is a *creature type,* like undead, construct, or monstrosity, and vampires are not of that creature type, even though you could describe their traditional body structure with the adjective "humanoid."

Comment: This is a good take. You highlight the fact that the DM can do whatever they want, *and* give a proper analysis of the rules as written.

Comment: To avoid confusing players who know how ghosts work, I would suggest the GM use not a ghost, but a Bloodgeist, a creature I just made up. It's very similar to a ghost, but with the ability to possess vampires. The PCs can discover its lore in an ancient tome.

Comment: The Vampire in the book is listed as a Medium Undead *(shapechanger)* - would this end up changing if the shapechanging ability had them shapechange *into* a humanoid form? It sounds like, if they were a bat, that would be a thing we would be avoiding.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st Being a shapechanger doesn't mean you can change into anything you want: it is a creature type (just like Undead or Humanoid). And vampires cannot change into a "humanoid form" (their stat block describes their bipedal form as "Vampire form.") However, even if they could, they would likely not be humanoids. The description of them turning into a bat states "Its statistics, other than its size and speed, are unchanged." As such, while transformed (e.g. into a bat) they are still undead (since creature type is one of their "statistics.")

Answer (score -5):

Most likely no. MM 5e says,

> One humanoid that the ghost can see within 5 feet of it must succeed
> on a DC 13 Charisma saving throw or be possessed by the ghost;

The MMA 5 describes humanoids as:

> The most common humanoid races are the ones most suitable as player
> characters: humans, dwarves, elves, and halflings. Almost as numerous
> but far more savage and brutal, and almost uniformly evil, are the
> races of goblinoids (goblins, hobgoblins, and bugbears), orcs,
> gnolls, lizardfolk, and kobolds.

And there you go. No vampires, ghouls or zombies.

Comment: FYI, probably the reason you're being downvoted is that your answer doesn't add anything that wasn't already covered in Louis's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/191149/62964).  This is exacerbated by the fact that this question and answer are nearly a year old.

Comment: No. That's not why. It's from another post. This is the changed one.